# Error while perfoming Row Edit in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to perform a row edit in primefaces databable. My problem is when I key in new value in  inputText in CellEditor 
and click edit (primefaces icon) onCellEdit method is calledsuccessfully but does not pick the newly value in the inputText it pick value that was initially in the datatable. What Am I doing wrong? I am using primefaces 3.5
Here in jsf code

```
<h:form id="form1">
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
        <p:panel header="Registered Devices" style="min-height: 400px;" id="paneldevices">
        <p:dataTable  emptyMessage="No Device Registered"  editable="true"  widgetVar="deviceTable" id="idGrid" value="#{deviceMgdBean.devices}" var="item" >
        <p:ajax  event="rowEdit" listener="#{deviceMgdBean.onCellEdit()}" update=":form1:messages"/>
        <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{deviceMgdBean.onCancel}" update=":form1:messages" />
        <p:column headerText="Options" style="width:50px">  
         <p:rowEditor  />  
        </p:column> 
        <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Device_name"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:cellEditor>  
        <f:facet name="output">  
       <h:outputText value="#{item.device_name}"/>
       </f:facet>  
       <f:facet name="input">  
      <p:inputText value="#{item.device_name}"  style="width:80%"  />
      </f:facet>  
       </p:cellEditor>                                    
       </p:column>
       </h:form>
```

Here is my managed Bean

```
 @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class DeviceMgdBean implements Serializable {
        public List<Devices> getDevices()
        {
            List<Devices> l=getDevdao().getDevices();//devices fetched from database

            return l;
        }
             public void onCellEdit(RowEditEvent event)
             {  
               Devices devo=(Devices) event.getObject();
               FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Device Edit","Test:"+devo.getDeviceName());  
               FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
             }  

        public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event)
        {  
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Item Cancelled");   
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg); 
            Devices devo=(Devices) event.getObject();
        }



    }
    class Devices {
    private int device_id;
    private String device_name;
    //getter and setters

    }
```

Comment: please indent your xhtml a little better

Comment: I think the value wants to be changed to `value="#{item.deviceName}"` if the getter in `Devices` is `getDeviceName()`

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<Devices> l;
public List<Devices> getDevices() {
   if(l==null) l=getDevdao().getDevices();//devices fetched from database
   return l;
}
```